# Why does my WordPress filter for overriding 'retrieve_password_message' not work while overriding 'retrieve_password_title' does work?

Tags: wordpress

I am having an issue trying to override the 'retrieve email' content on a WordPress site using the MemberPress plugin.

I added two functions for modifying the email. One for the email title, and one for the email content.  The 'retrieve_password_title' filter works but the 'retrieve_password_message' filter doesn't

```
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_title',
function( $title ) {
    $title = __( 'title' );
    return $title;
});

add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 
function( $message, $key, $user_login, $user_data ) {
    $message = __( 'message' );
    return $message;
}, 10, 4 ); // Note the '4' here, which indicates the number of arguments.
```

Comment: You may want to ask Memberpress support, since it's a paid plugin. That said, they have a specific hook for the password email title: https://docs.memberpress.com/article/329-filter-hooks-in-memberpress#mepr_user_pw_reset_title, but nothing for the message.